# Does overwriting a Float item in the ArrayList in Kotlin cause allocation?

Tags: android, kotlin

Im recalculating array values inside the ValueAnimator calls so I simply set the values over like

```
mValues[i] = newValue
```

Profiler tells me that a Float object is created here each time. There are recommendations for Java to use simple 'float' type here but in Kotlin, this is not an option.

Is that really like this that new Object is created during array update?

Answer (score 0):

Let's check this kotlin code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val list = ArrayList<Int>()
    list.add(0)
    list[0] = 10
}
```

Let's decompile it into Java class:

```
public final class AllocationKt {
   public static final void main(@NotNull String[] args) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(args, "args");
      ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
      list.add(0);
      list.set(0, 10);
   }
}
```

This is decompiled code. Doesn't look like new object was created (**at this point**).

And now let's check java code - source and decompiled:

```
public class Allocation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add(0);
        arrayList.set(0, 10);
    }
}
```

And decompiled:

```
public class Allocation {
    public Allocation() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList();
        arrayList.add(0);
        arrayList.set(0, 10);
    }
}
```

(Almost the same).

*Conclusion*: Assigning Int into `ArrayList<Int>` in Kotlin doesn't generate `new Integer(i)` in Java code. I've checked also for double - still, primitive is used in compiled code.

Update 1:
As I realized later, I've only proved that generated kotlin code is not different than Java code. But I forgot about one very important thing. **Generic type arguments must be reference types**. So, what happens when I try to put primitive `int` into list of `Integer`?

Autoboxing is the answer.

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes.

So, in bytecode your primitive `int` will became an `Integer`, your primitive `bool` will became `Boolean` and so on - whenever it's necessary.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this very empirical check. I wonder if the situation changes when you are not using constant values? I mean in real situation there is   mValues[i] = oldVaue + k * targetValue.  I still see allocation of Float exactly in this line and I cannot explain it.

Comment: Actually, ArrayList is generic class, so keep only reference object (generic type cannot keep primitive!). So, you are actually creating new object to put it in ArrayList in Kotlin and Java both. But it is not Kotlin issue but Java cancer. For you it doesn't matter, because of autoboxing. I will update my answer later, when I will have access to my pc.

Comment: Thank you again. You then write: "for you it does not matter", but as I see your explanation, an object WILL be created each time I update int element of the ArrayList, exactly because of autoboxing, right?

Comment: Yea, I meant in usage. For performance you should avoid Generic collections for primitives and use array (in Kotlin Array<Primitive>)

Answer (score 0):

Your title says `ArrayList`, the question itself says "array" twice. Those are different! If you can change to work with primitive arrays (`float[]` in Java and `FloatArray` in Kotlin), there will be no allocation.

If you do need a list (e.g. because you want size to change), consider using a primitive collection library: there are many of those for Java, all should be easy to use from Kotlin.